# Pandas is not reading the whole dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported necessary modules and stored the data in a dataset called hotel

```
hotel.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
new=pd.get_dummies(hotel,drop_first=True)
columns=list(new.columns)

print(new['is_canceled'].value_counts())
```

The output shows
0 156

1  15

But there are more than 40000 rows!!
Data=  https://drive.google.com/file/d/14lkRFIJtTM2gQMU8EVcIuPOi9sX9xTz8/view?usp=sharing
Can you figure out the error?
Thank you

Comment: just to clarify, what's the shape of "hotel"?

Comment: The actual shape is (40061,20) .But pycharm shows only (171,20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `value_counts()` your getting the number of occurrence of the element in that column.

So you have the number '0' -> 156 times and the number '1' -> 15  times

If you want to print the content of the column you need:

```
new['is_canceled'].values
```

And if you check, the shape of `new`, after dropna is 171,61

Comment: I need to count the number of occurrences of the elements in the column.There are 40061 rows.But 156+15 is not 40061.It is not reading the whole dataset

Comment: @Jay after you perform hotel.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True) your dataframe is reshaped to have 171 columns so exaclty 156 + 15